# How do I preserve a user setting's value when I change the setting's roaming property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, upgrade, settings, roaming

I've come to understand that I can preserve user settings from previous versions using code like this:

```
        if (Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
        {
            Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

However, that doesn't seem to work if I change a setting's roaming property. Is there any way to get the setting values to carry over and not reset when I change a setting from roaming to local or vice versa?

EDIT: I looked into a possible way to upgrade roaming settings to local settings using the [`GetPreviousVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.getpreviousversion(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but it doesn't work because if the previous version of a setting was roaming when the current setting isn't, the previous version isn't returned at all.

To reproduce:

1. Make a setting named MySetting.
2. Change MySetting's Roaming property to `true`.
3. Make sure MySetting's scope is `User`.
4. Run the following code:

   ```
       Console.WriteLine(Settings.Default.GetPreviousVersion("MySetting"));
       Settings.Default.MySetting = "Not the default value.";
       Settings.Default.Save();
   ```
5. Increment the assembly version.
6. Run the code again, noticing that the new value is outputted.
7. Change MySetting's Roaming property to `false`.
8. Increment the assembly version again.
9. Run the code again, noticing that the default value is outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which properties have changed from roaming=true to roaming=false, then you can manually add the `SettingsManageabilityAttribute` to the `SettingsProperty.Attributes` dictionary, use `GetPreviousVersion` to retrieve the previous value, then remove the attribute from the dictionary to clean-up:

```
Console.WriteLine("Current: {0}", Settings.Default.MySetting);
// we don't see the previous value here...
Console.WriteLine("Previous: {0}", Settings.Default.GetPreviousVersion("MySetting"));
// ...so we manually add the SettingsManageabilityAttribute to it...
var setting = Settings.Default.Properties["MySetting"];
setting.Attributes.Add(typeof(SettingsManageabilityAttribute), new SettingsManageabilityAttribute(SettingsManageability.Roaming));
// ...retrieve the previous value...
Console.WriteLine("Previous: {0}", Settings.Default.GetPreviousVersion("MySetting"));
// ...and then clean up after ourselves by removing the attribute.
setting.Attributes.Remove(typeof(SettingsManageabilityAttribute));
// ...now we don't see the previous value anymore.
Console.WriteLine("Previous: {0}", Settings.Default.GetPreviousVersion("MySetting"));
```